# Documents requests and memory issue using MongoDB

Tags: python, performance, memory, mongodb

I have documents in Mongo that contain questionnaire-like data (company's name, address, phone numbers, etc.). I should have this data displayed in web interface.

How to make it better: get the whole document as dict into a variable and fill webform from its data or make lots of database requests to fill each field of the web form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to display *all* of the data on the web interface anyways, start simple: Get a the whole document.  It reduces your latency by requiring less round trips to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with GPS - if you need all, or most, of the data then it should be a better option to retrieve the document in one request as opposed to hitting the database x number of times.